# I am trying to add a plugin in Joomla and it gives me a fatal error

Tags: php, joomla, syntax-error

Fatal error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsf\libraries\joomla\cache\storage\memcache.php on line 435

```
protected function lockindex()
{
    $looptime = 300;
    $data_lock = self::$_db->add($this->_hash . '-index_lock', 1, false, 30);

    if ($data_lock === false)
    {

        $lock_counter = 0;

        // Loop until you find that the lock has been released.  that implies that data get from other thread has finished
        while ($data_lock === false)
        {
            if ($lock_counter > $looptime)
            {
                return false;
                break;
            }

            usleep(100);
            $data_lock = self::$_db->add($this->_hash . '-index_lock', 1, false, 30);
            $lock_counter++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's an excerpt from the Joomla! source code, isn't it?  Since the problem is almost certainly being caused indirectly by your plugin, we'll need to know what your plugin is doing in order to be able to help you.

Comment: it happens with every single plugin i try to install

Comment: is your cache supposed to be in memcache? Have you tried switching it to file?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the configuration.php and change to this setting.

```
public $caching = '0';
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $cachetime = '15';
```

instead of:-

```
public $caching = '0';
public $cache_handler = 'memcache';
public $cachetime = '30';
public $memcache_persist = '1';
public $memcache_compress = '0';
public $memcache_server_host = 'mem';
public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
```

This will fix the fatal crash error by switching it manually to file.